# Mocking a inner function(or even more deep) for testing in go

Tags: unit-testing, go

is there a way to achieve this? I want to Mock the response of a function call from within another function call. Example

**main.go**

```
type Crs struct {}
func (cr crs)TheFunction() error {
   // Some code
   _ := ToMockResponse(hello string)
   return nil
}

func ToMockResponse() error {
    return somerror
}
```

and in my test file

**main_test.go**

```
func TestTheFunction(t *testing.T) {
    cr = Crs{}
    mockInstance = new(randomMock)
    mockInstance.On("ToMockResponse").Return(nil)

    err := cr.TheFunction()
    assert.NoError(t, err)
}
```

I'm not sure if what I did is correct. What I'm trying to achieve is that I just want to have a Mock response of ToMockResponse whenever it's being called inside TheFunction

I have seen and read most of the tutorial but all of them shows a Mock response from a method of a class. But there are no function-to-function mocking samples. Hope you can provide a solution to this.

Comment: *"is there a way to achieve this?"* -- "this"? No, there isn't. Functions, including concrete type methods, cannot be mocked.

Comment: Don't mock. Mocking is a bad technique in Go.

Comment: @Volker why? can you refer me to the article?
i don't get no as in answer, please give more details. it must be a best practice to mock a func.

Comment: You seem to be testing methods on this `Crs` type, which are defined in your `main` package, and these methods seem to be calling eachother internally. If you have to mock one of these internal calls on the type you're testing, your _type_ is badly written. To me, your wanting to do this just tells me that the code is implemented badly

Comment: @Volker: That's a very broad brush you're painting with there. There are plenty of situations where mocking is a great way to test. Mocking isn't bad or evil per se, it's all about what you mock, and how it fits in with what you're testing. Complex, concurrent code bases don't just work with argument/returns, but have internal channels and something like a multiplexer that emits events. Rather than implementing a receiver in your tests, mocking the multiplexer to see the events coming in can make tests much, much more readable and maintainable. Mocking a DB is also valid

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem yes you right, fixed the code. now is there a way to mock the inner function?

Comment: @DevFromI: No. That goes against the point of unit testing. The function is part of the package you're testing. A test calling `TheFunction` should follow the standard code path within your package, because that's what you're trying to test. Mocking or stubbing out part of the package you're actually testing means you are no longer testing the package, you're just testing your test. You should never find yourself needing to do this

Comment: Mocking the Java/PHP/… way is a) often not possible in Go (see your code) and b) mocks often are the worst test doubles (fakes or even stubs often lead to better tests). Note that _sometimes_ a mock is the best test strategy, but in Go almost never.

Comment: @Volker Oh, I see what you mean now... OK, I agree with that, then... I've not done any Java or PHP in ages, I've taken to using _mocks_ as a catch-all term, but what I tend to call mocks are more accurately described as stubs or fakes

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into whether you should do this, and assuming that you have a valid reason to do so, one way to mock functions is to use them via a level of indirection.  You can then substitute a suitable alternative in your indirection for the purposes of testing.

An interface is one way to achieve that, but GoLang supports functions as values, so another way is to use a simple variable of an appropriate function type:

Adapted to your example, this might look similar to:

```golang
var toMockResponse = ToMockResponse

func (cr crs)TheFunction() error {
   // Some code
   _ := toMockResponse(hello string)
   return nil
}

func ToMockResponse() error {
    return somerror
}
```

and your test:

```golang
func TestTheFunction(t *testing.T) {
    cr = Crs{}
    ofn := toMockResponse
    toMockResponse = func(string) error { return nil }
    defer func() { toMockResponse = ofn }()

    err := cr.TheFunction()
    assert.NoError(t, err)
}
```

I have assumed that you need to export the `ToMockResponse`; the function variable is deliberately ***not*** exported so that it cannot be manipulated outside of the package itself.

If the function being redirected is *itself* not exported, denying the ability to use the case difference of exported vs non-exported symbols to differentiate them, then you may need to be a bit more creative with your naming.  e.g. a variable called `toMockResponseFn`.

### Footnote

`ofn` is mnemonic for "original function".  In a more complicated test you can preserve the pattern by creating a scope for each `ofn` you need (`defer` operates w.r.t the containing function, not the scope):

```golang
   {
      ofn := toMockResponse
      toMockResponse = func(string) error { return nil }
      defer func() { toMockResponse = ofn }()
   }
   {
      ofn := now
      now = func() time.Time { return time.Date(..etc..) }
      defer func() { now = ofn }()
   }
```

Comment: Thank you!
I'm going also with the interface approach, does it's different from what you suggested?

Comment: It essentially has the same effect, with the addition of two type decls, one to implement the production implementation and the other to implement the mock (vs just 1 variable and 2 implementations of a func).  You also need some way to "inject" a reference to a particular implementation.  That additional complexity might be acceptable (or even necessary) if you have more complex testing needs.  There's no "One True Way", only a toolbox of options.  I use both techniques, according to the most appropriate (i.e. most simple) in each case. :)